# How to call itertools.pruduct function with list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I'm trying to use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function to create all combinations of sentences from lists of alternative words. The input is a list of lists that each element is a list of alternative words. For example:

```
text_input  = [['The'],
               ['apple', 'banana'],
               ['is'], 
               ['green', 'red']]
```

And the desired output list of all permutation of one word from each list:

```
[['The apple is red'],
 ['The banana is red'],
 ['The apple is green'],
 ['The banana is green']]
```

But when I try to do something like:

```
print(list(itertools.product(text_input)))
>>> [(['The'],), (['apple', 'banana'],), (['is'],), (['green', 'red'],)]
```

In contrast `print(list(itertools.product(text_input[0], text_input[1],text_input[2],text_input[3])))` works as desired -- but I don't want to specify elements everytime. Some times, the list have dozen of elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the list using the `*` operator:

```
list(itertools.product(*text_input))
# [('The', 'apple', 'is', 'green'), 
#  ('The', 'apple', 'is', 'red'), 
#  ('The', 'banana', 'is', 'green'), 
#  ('The', 'banana', 'is', 'red')]
```